# You should not use <Link> outside a <Router> error after using <Link> in component being rendered by ReactDOM.render()

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So, I have a menu that is being rendered just after clicking on some another component by:
`ReactDOM.render()`
In this menu there is a  component which causes problem in the title.

```
const ProfileMenu = props => {
    return(
        <div>
            <div className={`arrow-thing ${props.addClass1}`}></div>
            <div className={`profile-menu ${props.addClass2}`}>
                <div className="profile-menu-container">
                    <Link to="/profile"><div className={`profile-menu-button ${props.addClass3}`}>Profile</div></Link>
                    <Link to="/settings"><div className={`profile-menu-button ${props.addClass3}`}>Settings</div></Link>
                    <div className={`profile-menu-button ${props.addClass3}`}>Logout</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have tried to create another `<BrowserRouter>` element around `<Link>` element, but in this way, the path is changed, but nothing happens. How can I use my routes in my main app.js file for this rendered component?
Edit: Of course there is classic Router and route tags hierarchy in main app.js and in every case of routing except this everything is working as usual

Comment: Pls share the full code snippet to help us understand. Your Link and Routes must all have a Router provider higher up in the tree.

Comment: is `ProfileMenu` wrapped by `BrowserRouter` ? for sure not, that you see this error

Comment: ProfileMenu is rendered after clicking on avatar in header and that's the main problem, because it don't exist until it renders and even after it renders it dont get the routing from higher hierarchy. Buttons in header work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would have your router quite high up in the tree, preferably on the very top.

This way your entire application is inside a `<Router />`, and therefore you would be able to access `<Link />` and `<Route />` components anywhere.

The way I personally do it, is have the `<App />` component render `<Router />`, then my entire page goes into the `<Router />` tag. Then you can use `<Link />` wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap BrowserRouter on the App itself for this error to go away

```
const AppWithRouter =() => (<BrowserRouter>
                                <App/>
                            </BrowserRouter>);
ReactDOM.render(<AppWithRouter/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

as for sometime you cant always be in the Route , Switch etc component to receive the history or Link , you can use withRouter to wrap the component with .

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const ProfileMenu = props => {
    return(
        <div>
            <div className={`arrow-thing ${props.addClass1}`}></div>
            <div className={`profile-menu ${props.addClass2}`}>
                <div className="profile-menu-container">
                    <Link to="/profile"><div className={`profile-menu-button ${props.addClass3}`}>Profile</div></Link>
                    <Link to="/settings"><div className={`profile-menu-button ${props.addClass3}`}>Settings</div></Link>
                    <div className={`profile-menu-button ${props.addClass3}`}>Logout</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export withRouter(ProfileMenu);
```